# ScrollView not respecting flex rules

Tags: react-native, flexbox

This results in a screen that is half blue and half yellow, should it not be 2/3 yellow?

```
    <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column'}}>
       <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor: 'blue'}}></View>
       <ScrollView style={{flex:2}} contentContainerStyle={{flex:1,backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}></ScrollView>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you are right, but react native's ScrollView behaves a little bit differently. As you can read in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview):

> Keep in mind that ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to
>   work, since they contain unbounded-height children into a bounded
>   container (via a scroll interaction). In order to bound the height of
>   a ScrollView, either set the height of the view directly (discouraged)
>   or make sure all parent views have bounded height. Forgetting to
>   transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack can lead to errors here, which
>   the element inspector makes easy to debug.

In order to achieve your wanted behavior, you can do the following:

```
<View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column'}}>
       <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor: 'blue'}}></View>
       <View style={{flex:2}}> // surround scrollview with flex 2 
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1,backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}></ScrollView>
       </View>
</View>
```